# 1998 Ford Contour P0171 P0174

Tags: engine, ford, obd-ii, leak, cdw27

I have a 1998 Ford Contour that has a check engine light. I checked the codes, and found:

- P0171 System Too Lean (Bank 1)
- P0174 System Too Lean (Bank 2)
- P0401 Insufficient EGR Flow
- P1131 Lack of Upstream Heated Oxygen Sensor Switch - Sensor Indicates Lean - Bank No. 1

I think the main culprit might be a vacuum leak, and that the codes are related to the side effects caused by the leak. Are there any common hoses that I should check first? I remember we had two main hoses on BMWs that were usually the guilty party.

Comment: Checked for leaks, and found none. I did find that the fuel pump might not be coming on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem did end up being the fuel pump. Checked wires and fuses, but in the end it was a bad pump. The filter was also replaced, and can probably be blamed for the pump failing.